# How to build different UI based on ProfileType in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter, I want to render different UI in my app based of ProfileType i.e. if a user is 'Club', it will show a '+' icon for adding a event, otherwise not. I stored userData in firestore like here:[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWWhZ.jpg)

I stored extra user info like this in **main.dart** :

```
  if (isLogin) {
    authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  
  } else {
    authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(authResult.user.uid)
        .set({
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'profileType': profileType,
      'SignUpDate': timestamp,
    });
  }
}
```

I also extracted userId while building screens:

```
    home: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
      
      
      if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
        var arr = userSnapshot.data.toString().split(',');
      
      String arr1 = arr[17].split(',').toString();
      String uid = arr1.split(':')[1].split(')')[0];
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  print('---Data-----');
  print(doc.data());
     });
        return Home(uid: uid,);
      }
      return AuthScreen();
    },
  ),
);
```

But i failed to get 'profileType' for build UI. I searched for 'profileType' with this

```
findProfileType()  {
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  print('---Data-----');
  print(doc.data());
     });
}
```

But everytime it returned null. Any suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you getting user id ?

Comment: yes. but when i ran query to search 'profileType' with the userid i got, it becomes a async operation always passing null on execution and giving error on build

Comment: in your findProfileType did you try placing an await before your request?

Comment: yes, it has no effect, it always build the default UI. Also I tried to log the result, but it logged null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `findProfileType` function is returning null because there is no explicit return statement inside the function. See the documentation [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#return-values) for more information.

Given that `findProfileType` is asynchronous you could use a `FutureBuilder` widget to build the UI. The data from the snapshot could be used to determine which UI to build.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Stream<String> _stream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );

    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: _stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

          if (snapshot.data == 'Club') {
            floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            );
          }

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: appBar,
            body: Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.data),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: appBar,
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _stream = FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .asyncMap(
          (user) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(user.uid)
              .get(),
        )
        .map(
          (doc) => doc.data()['profileType'],
        );
  }
}
```

I would recommend taking a look at the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for more information. Please do not hesitate to let me know if you have any questions or would like more information!

Comment: Can I keep my code for 'home: ' same as in the 2nd code snippet in my question. Actually, I have created main.dart only till 2nd code snippet. From there I passed by fetched User ID in my separate Home.dart file.

Comment: and should I keep 2nd line of code commented?

Comment: Hi @SumitThakur, I have updated the code sample to align it more closely with the second code snippet in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much @tnc1997, i had been stuck here for 2 days.

Comment: the code you gave worked absolutely fine. Now ahead in my project I need more data during signin. I removed arrow func and used braces in initState, now what happens is, if I signin a new user, it always build UI without '+' option. But it get self fixed if i restart the app. However, it is not the case if I login existing user, for login it works well. Can u please tell something about this. Here is my current status with your code https://github.com/sumitt1080/Nuget/blob/master/lib/pages/home.dart